# i don't know how to fix login form like this

Tags: php, session, if-statement, authentication

error like this:

[image: error screenshot]

and here my code login.php

```
 <?php if(isset($_SESSION['confirmation_success'])); ?>
               <div class="alert alert-success"> <?php echo $_SESSION['confirmation_success']; ?></div>

                <?php unset($_SESSION['confirmation_success']); ?>
```

code above is n login in line 16.

Comment: Consider adding php to the tags, that makes your question easier to find for the people that may be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

There are errors in your code:

Instead of using `{` you are written `;` in the `if` condition.

Assuming that the blocks needed to be in an `if` loop

I have modified your code, and check if it is working in the context.

```
    <?php if(isset($_SESSION['confirmation_success'])) { ?>
    <div class="alert alert-success"> <?php echo $_SESSION['confirmation_success']; ?> </div>

   <?php unset($_SESSION['confirmation_success']); } ?>
```

Comment: means your login not working as expected. I cant help you without checking your code.